# Are multiple elements each with an addEventListener allowed?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, delegation

I would like the specified function to be called only if the correct button is clicked on.

```
function callback(func){
func();
}
```

The main function(s) and their results:

Attempt A:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num2').addEventListener('click', callback(function2));

});
```

Result: Opening the page and clicking any of the buttons will run function1

Attempt B:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function () {

document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num2').addEventListener('click', callback(function2));

});
```

Result: Clicking anywhere on the page will run function1

Attempt C:

```
document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num2').addEventListener('click', callback(function2));
```

Result: Opening the page and clicking on the buttons will run function1 and reload the page

Attempt D:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function () {

//The first ID doesn't exist
document.getElementById('imaginaryNum1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num2').addEventListener('click', callback(function2));

});
```

Result: Clicking anywhere on the page will run function1

Attempt E:

```
//The first ID doesn't exist
document.getElementById('imaginaryNum1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num1').addEventListener('click', callback(function1));
document.getElementById('num2').addEventListener('click', callback(function2));
```

Result: Opening the page and clicking on the buttons will run function1 and reload the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, why wouldn't it be. Looking at your code, though, you might be better of *delegating the event*: [it's not that hard](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/). Basically, listen for the event you need on a level in the dom that contains each of the individual elements, and write your handler in such a way that you check if the element that fired the event is of interest, if so: handle the event, if not, just return. 
You're also missing the third argument, that `addEventListener` expects: a boolean, indicating weather you want to handle the event during the capturing phase, or the bubbling phase, [read a couple of articles on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html), in particular on the [distinct phases](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

I've also noticed that you're doing weird things with your handler function, you're going to have some issues with that. Basically, what `addEventListener` expects as a second argument is *a reference to a function*, you're passing the return value of a function (which is undefined in your case).

```
function clickHandler(e)//accept event argument
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (!target.id.match(/num[0-9]/))
    {//the clicked element doesn't have num1, num2, num3... as id, no need to handle this event
        return e;
    }
    //handle event. target is a reference to the clicked element
}
document.body.addEventListener('click',clickHandler,false);//<-- just the function name, no parentheses
```

That's all you need, one listener that'll handle all click events.

Here are a couple of JS questions that I've posted that deal with event delegation, take a look at the code, read the articles I linked to, you'll soon work it out.
[delegating the change event in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331203/javascript-how-to-simulate-change-event-in-internet-explorer-delegation) -- tricky
[avoid mem-leaks in IE<9 with `onload` listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186750/memory-leak-risk-in-javascript-closures): my answer to the question
[Augmenting the event prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617014/javascript-event-prototype-in-ie8) in IE<9 using delegation

Comment: OK. So I added the above by I got: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null nonExtension05.html:120
(anonymous function)

Comment: did you define a function called `clickHandler` - and did you make sure that the DOM was loaded when this code ran? if not: add the function with the correct name, and use one of the load-listeners of the questions I linked. Also: `addEventListener` isn't supported by IE<9, you'll have to rely on `attachEvent` if you're testing in that browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. Partial to this article though: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate. :)

Answer (score 3):

`callback` immediately executes the function that is passed into it - so it is never passed to  the `addEventListener` - instead, `undefined` is passed.

`.addEventListener('someEvent', callback(functionN), false)` is essentially `.addEventListener('someEvent', (function(){ functionN() })(), false)`.

Change to `.addEventListener('someEvent', functionN, false)` and see what happens - if you are still getting errors take a look in the Script Panel of your web browser and see what errors are being generated.