# Separating DOM elements for click events

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a website which displays search results. The results are displayed with headline information of the full item. The html of each search result looks like this:

```
<article class="search_result" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;">

// Search result data

</article>
```

As you can see, I have made it so that you can click anywhere and access the result in more detail

However, within the search result, I have also included a button which performs another function.

The problem I have is when you click on the button, both the button and the search result receive the click event and act upon it. If the button is clicked, I dont want the search result to handle it as well.

How can I sort this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is event bubbling and capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: You would stop the event from propagating up the DOM. See the link Diodeus posted, in addition to the documentation for `event.stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript events bubble up the DOM by default, so events triggered on a children will be triggered on the parent.

To prevent this, you need to stop the propagation of the event.

This is done by:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Note that `event` is usually passed as a parameter to your callback functions. (Meaning, don't use `onclick=""` attributes so you get function callback)

Full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation
(IE < 8 fallback: [Prototype Event.StopPropagation for IE >= 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102300/prototype-event-stoppropagation-for-ie-8))